# Twig Form Theming - form_label class attribute

Tags: symfony, twig

I've been trying to override the form_row Twig extension so I can render a Twitter Bootstrap style row. A twitter boostrap form row should look like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="idOfMainInput">Label Name:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="idOfMainInput" name="someDumbName">
    </div>
</div>
```

The base twig div style form_row block is defined in [this link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) as below:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div>
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

So, my thoughts were to just put the necessary divs in, and hard code where necessary the class entries (i.e. in the main div) but pass the 'attr' value to the form_label, form_errors and form_widget sections. I've taken out form_errors for now, just so I don't get too deep into it. Here's what I tried:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
<div class="control-group">
    {{ form_label(form, 'test label name', { 'attr': {'class': 'control-label'} }) }}
    <div class="controls">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

The problem, though, is no matter what I try, the form_label extension does not use "control-label" as my class (and it should according to the source code append it if there's existing ones, like "required"). Here's what I get when I view the source of the rendered page:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="form_rsa_id" class="required">test label name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" id="form_rsa_id" name="form[rsa_id]" required="required" />
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the class="required" is there and is taken from the base form object attributes, but it should be class="required control-label", which it's not.

Kinda at a loss here, as the documentation (as well as the source) states that one should use the notation "form_label(view, label, variables)". Link to docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-label-view-label-variables).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641727/apply-class-to-symfony2-form-label

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you need to use `label_attr` rather than `attr`.

Comment: For Symfony 2.1 is `label_attr`

Comment: Thanks @Erioch, just for informational purposes, found it in the docs just now: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking to do this, Symfony 2.6 comes with a [Bootstrap form theme](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme) which will do this for you.